# indicator-sound is crashing and VLC or any media player does not open

Tags: video, vlc, crash, indicator-sound

Whenever I try to open VLC media player from dashboard, it doesn't open. When I try to open any video file by double clicking on it, Ubuntu shows me the following error message:

**Sorry Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error.** Details are in the following screenshot:

[image: indicator-sound is crashing]

Please someone resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

N.B. Rythmbox music player is playing audios without any problem and  I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem this morning after messing around with VLC (changing some preferences, trying to add a skin, attempting to get bookmarking working). Finally I went into `~/.config/vlc` and deleted everything – next time I started VLC, all was well.